# Frameworks for building so-called CRUD Admin UIs (over SQL tables)

Tags: user-interface, frameworks, crud, administration

What frameworks are targeted specifically at building so-called "CRUD Admin UIs" (basically, a set of screens for editing related SQL tables), whether Web Apps or Thick Clients.

The ones I know of:

- **ASP.NET DynamicData**
- **Django Admin** (from Nick's answer below)

General purpose frameworks like **Ruby-on-Rails** and **ASP.NET MVC** don't count.

Comment: Not answering because I haven't used it professionaly, but I believe scafolding on ruby on rails allows this with VERY few lines of code.

Comment: Asp.net Dynamic Data is too incomprehensible to me?  Are you trying to understand it by reading The documentation, or have you watched the videos?  The videos are simple enough that I was able to follow along and create a Dynamic Data site for an existing database while watching the videos.  This was after I had tried learning about it by reading the documentation and given it up as a bad job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://devpicayune.com/pycon2008/django_admin.html

Once you have your models setup, Django's admin is a very powerful, easy-to-use, and extensible interface.

Answer (score 0):

Based on those requirements; i'd have to say plain old ASP.NET GridViews bound to a SQLDataSource.

You'll never even need to open the code editor!